# Show background color for every time period (Eg. January or quater) a few years back

Tags: pine-script

I would like to display background color for ALL quarters on a chart a few years back.

I have this working example, but there is a problem. The for loop does not work properly, because it only draws background for the last year (instead of coloring all the years back).

Please help. :)

```
//// DISPLAY BACKGROUND COLOR FOR EVERY QUATER A FEW YEARS BACK
//@version=4
getMonthNumber(value) => 
    currentMonth = month
    amountToSubtract = (12 - value) % 12
    abs(currentMonth - (currentMonth - amountToSubtract))
    
getMonth(monthNumber, yearsBack) =>
    oneYear = 31556952000 // ms
    timestamp(year(timenow - oneYear * yearsBack), month(timenow) - getMonthNumber(monthNumber), 1, 0, 0, 0)

getEndOfDecember(yearsBack) =>
    oneYear = 31556952000 // ms
    timestamp(year(timenow - oneYear * (yearsBack - 1)), month(timenow) - getMonthNumber(1), 1, 0, 0, 0)

q1 = false
q2 = false
q3 = false
q4 = false

DRAW_YEARS_BACK = 1
for i = 0 to DRAW_YEARS_BACK // PROBLEM: draws only the last year (instead of all)
    q1 := time > getMonth(1, i) and time < getMonth(4, i) 
    q2 := time > getMonth(4, i) and time < getMonth(7, i)
    q3 := time > getMonth(7, i) and time < getMonth(10, i)
    q4 := time > getMonth(10, i) and time < getEndOfDecember(i)

bgcolor(color = q1 ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(color = q2 ? color.yellow : na)
bgcolor(color = q3 ? color.orange : na)
bgcolor(color = q4 ? color.silver : na)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("colors")
q = month < 4 ? color.green : month < 7 ? color.yellow : month < 10 ? color.orange : color.silver
bgcolor(q)
```

There you go

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).